# How to write a list of path names on separate rows in csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of pathnames:

```
li = [u"C:\\temp\\fileA.shp", u"C:\\temp\\fileB.shp", u"C:\\temp\\fileC.shp"]
```

I am trying to write each path on a separate line in a txt file. This is what I have done so far:

```
import csv

li = [u"C:\\temp\\fileA.shp", u"C:\\temp\\fileB.shp", u"C:\\temp\\fileC.shp"]

with open(r'C:\temp\myfile.csv', "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerows([li])
```

Which yields a list of files on the same row:

```
C:\temp\fileA.shp,C:\temp\fileB.shp,C:\temp\fileC.shp
```

How can I tweak this so that the pathnames are each on their own row? The following is what I am after:

```
C:\temp\fileA.shp
C:\temp\fileB.shp
C:\temp\fileC.shp
```

Comment: The linked question has the answer to your problem. If you are directly writing to a txt file, you do not need to use CSV.

Answer (score -1):

Easy just need to add \n witch means new

```
import csv

li = [u"C:\\temp\\fileA.shp", u"C:\\temp\\fileB.shp", u"C:\\temp\\fileC.shp"]

with open(r'C:\temp\myfile.txt', "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f + '\n', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerows([li])
```

So now f will be printed + \n (new line)

Comment: I get an error with this: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'file' and 'str'`

Comment: Sorry try now made change.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, I get the same error.

Comment: You are aware that you want a list. Cvs stands for Comma Sperated Vale. If you want a list make it a .txt

Comment: `f` is a file object, and you trying to add `'\n'` to it.